# Node.js server restart drops the sessions

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm having fully functional user signup / authentication system using Express and Connect middleware.

```
app.use(express.session({store: require('connect').session.MemoryStore( {reapInterval: 60000 * 10} ) }))
```

The only problem is that sessions drop every time you perform server restart.

[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) restarts Node.js every time it detects a file change.

How can I have persistent sessions?

Comment: I am wondering how to have persistent sessions using JWTs instead of using a database...??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like your code is telling you are using MemoryStore. This is volatile and gets cleared on restart. I would advise you to use [connect_redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) to persist your session. Redis is an extremely fast store.

1. Download [redis](http://redis.io/download)
2. compile redis: `make`
3. Start server: `./redis-server`
4. `npm install connect-redis`
5. ```
   var connect = require('connect') , RedisStore = require('connect-redis');

   connect.createServer(
     connect.cookieParser(),
     // 5 minutes
     connect.session({ store: new RedisStore })
   );
   ```

This is just to get you started quickly. You should read the documentation and configure redis if you want to get most out of redis.

Comment: Just curious why do you use ProperCase for RedisStore, is there a NodeJS convention/reason for this?

Comment: @ClarenceLiu Class names are often chosen to be ProperCase (or CamelCase or what you want to call it).

Comment: Ah cool, well camelCase to me starts with a lower case, but I do like this convention.

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to get Redis on track using express.js, Google sent me here. The express implementation changed:

```
var express = require('express'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
```

Another important thing is the order of express configurations.

```
app.configure(function(){

    app.enable('strict routing'); // removes trailing slash
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jqtpl');
    app.register('.html', require('jqtpl').express);
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.compiler({src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['sass']}));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: _.config.secret, store: new RedisStore}));

});
```

`cookieParser` & session configurations need to be at the end of the configurations, and `cookieParser` must be placed right before `express.session`.

Hope that helps, I ran in both of these problems.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with everybody about Redis, but I think that different technologies are a problem in terms of software maintenance. If you are using MongoDB for example there is connect-mongo (https://npmjs.org/package/connect-mongo), if you are using MySQL there is connect-MySQL (https://npmjs.org/package/connect-mysql), connect-couchdb for CouchDB (https://npmjs.org/package/connect-couchdb) and so on.

Answer (score 6):

also, if you're using express, you need to provide a secret when telling the app to use the redis middleware.

so, follow Alfred's recipe above, but do the following...

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis');

app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use( express.session( { secret: "keyboard cat", store: new RedisStore }));
```

Comment: Now you need to add require('connect-redis')(express) - otherwise you get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined. (https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/issues/24)

Answer (score 1):

When node dies I would imagine the memory store you're using dies.

Persist the sessions to disk?

Comment: as redis handles the session in an additional process the session survives node crashes and node restarts, if redis goes down, sessions go down accordingly