# My Node/Express session expires with every change to my code

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am working on a local Node/Express app and am using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

To test my code, I need to log into a user account. Every time I make a change in my code - even if I just add a space - the session ends and I get logged out. With no changes, my session persists as intended. Why?

Here's how my session is set:

```
var day = 60000*60*24;
req.session.expires = new Date(Date.now() + (30*day));          
req.session.cookie.maxAge = (30*day);
```

I am using [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), so my server restarts on every save. Is this why?

**EDIT**: looks like the issue is with restarting the server, not with the code change. Relevant answers here:

(1) [Express 4 Sessions not persisting when restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260676/express-4-sessions-not-persisting-when-restarting-server)

(2) [Node.js server restart drops the sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286073/node-js-server-restart-drops-the-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is with restarting the server, not with the code change. By default, sessions are stored in MemoryStore. Relevant answers here:

(1) [Express 4 Sessions not persisting when restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260676/express-4-sessions-not-persisting-when-restarting-server)

(2) [Node.js server restart drops the sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286073/node-js-server-restart-drops-the-sessions)